# Different heights for 2 different reusable cells in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview with 2 different custom cells, both with their own unique cell reusable identifier. I need these to each have a different height. my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` looks like this:

```
  //3
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell? {

   let PostObject = object as! Post

    if PostObject["fichierimage"] as? PFFile == nil {

        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell10", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell0Entry

        return cell2

    }
    else {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell9", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell4

        return cell

    }

}
```

This works to correctly load all of the data into the tableview. But the height of both cells remains at 481, whereas the height of the first one should be 99. I set its height to 99 in the storyboard but I think the tableView row height overrode it. I tried this in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, but it did not work, it throws an error and crashes the app:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let object1 = objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    let object2 = object1 as! Post


    // this next line throws the error
    if object2["fichierimage"] as? PFFile == nil {
        return 99
    }
    else {
        return 481
    }
}
```

The error message says:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', 
>        reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]

Comment: In the attributes inspector try changing tableview content to "Static cells". You can design each cell separately. Also you can change the height of each cell simply by dragging them within the storyboard.

Comment: i tried that, but I am using a PFQueryTableViewController and not a UITableviewController so I got an error message "static cells can only be embedded in a UITableViewController"

Answer (score 0):

modify

```
// this next line throws the error
if object2["fichierimage"] as? PFFile == nil {
    return 99
}
else {
    return 481
}
```

To this:

```
if let _ = object2["fichierimage"] as? PFFile {
    return 99
}
else {
    return 481
}
```

Tell me if it works

Comment: that still did not work, I received the error message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

Comment: So it's this line : 

let object1 = objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)

which crash your app. Test indexPath.row and your objectAtIndexPath.count .

EDIT: i might guess that your objectAtIndexPath has 2 elements (0..1) and your localIndexPath from the datasource tableview point beyond this

Comment: honestly I'm new to programming and aren't sure exactly what you mean by "testing" indexPath.row. I added a println(objectatindexPath(NsIndexPath) ) to the heightforrowatindexpata section, and it did print the object details to the console, so something is there, it isn't nil as far as I can tell.

Comment: Another option that I have thought of is using the same cell, but just setting the height of the image view to 0, and then trying to resize the size of that one cell. I'm playing with that option right now.

Comment: to be honest, your code need to be completely re-written. You must not have params/variables/constants just called object1, object2 or even objectAtIndexPath like you do.

I want to help you but this ... messy code, we can't. Sorry, try to be less generic in your name convention. I advice you to read [This article about best practice](https://github.com/github/swift-style-guide). 

Cheers from France / jlngdt - juliengdt